# how to make my code looks like ajax in jquery style

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I know that the question in a little bit confusing but this is the idea:

I'm doing a library with JavaScript and trying to copy some jQuery's style. I have a function which will receive 3 parameters and i would like to do it like AJAX in jQuery.

Example:

I'd like that my function to look like this

```
$.ajax({
url: "url",
dataType: post,
etc etc
});
```

but with my code:

```
Stone.ValidateNumber({
InputElementId: "Some Input's ID",
MessageDestiny:  "Other html element's ID"
TrueResults: "#333",    //if the validation is true
FalseRetuls: "RED",    //if the validation is false(I dont know if this could work or could be a function, but i dont know, and thats why i came here)

})
```

Note: this IS just a example. What I want is to know to do that.

Comment: You need to take an associative array as argument.

Comment: Have you tried it yet? This is not a question we can narrowly answer.

Comment: You are not passing three parameters, you are passing one parameter which happens to be an object literal containing three fields.

Comment: @ATOzTOA: You mean an object :-)

Comment: @ppeterka it looks cool and ive always wondered how does that work

Comment: Someone edited my question and now its not clears enougth

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what jQuery doing is to have one object parameter.

example:

```
Stone.ValidateNumber = function( params ) {
   alert( "InputElementId = " params.InputElementId );
   alert( "TrueResults= " params.TrueResults );
   alert( "FalseRetuls= " params.FalseRetuls );


}
```

here is a way to achieve the ajax style:

```
var $ = {}; //$ equal to new object
$.ajax = function(options) {
   alert( options.data );
}
$.get = function( options ) {
   this.ajax( { data : 'hello', url: 'http://www.google.com' } );
}
```

Comment: but the style is like a normal function. Or im missing something?

Comment: what do you mean normal function?

Comment: I know how make that, and also i did but i trying to make it look like JQuery has AJAX's style. Look the question again. Moreover im trying to learn how does it works passing parramaters in that way(it not just matters of style)

Comment: ok i think i understand first i suggest you to read all the jQuery JavaScript 101 Tutorial check this: http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/functions/ it's explains javascript functions and i also suggest you to learn OOP in javascript

Comment: OMG its working so well!! thank men!! (even if it is so late)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
ValidateNumber(myDict) {
    input = myDict["InputElementId"];
    t_results = myDict["TrueResults"];
    f_results = myDict["FalseResults"];

    // Process data
}
```

Comment: I understand but, how do i process the data?

Comment: What does your Stone class do?

Comment: is the name of the library, like JQuey "$". The function of that library is for input validations only like just accept Numbers, strings, date formats etc etc.

Comment: That will be what you do in `process data`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ?

```
Stone.ValidateNumber = function(first){

if (Object.keys(first).length) == 1)
{
    //make sure that all elements are defined (typeof != 'undefined')
 if (first.InputElementId == 'valid_rule')
     return first.TrueResults;
  else
     return first.FalseRetuls;
}
```